# How to find a more efficient way of solving this problem from Pyschool?

Tags: python, string

> Write the function startWithVowel(word) that takes in a word as argument and returns a substring that starts with the first vowel found in the word. The function returns 'No vowel' if the word does not contain vowel.

Below code is running fine but I want to improve my skills. Any tips?

```
def startWithVowel(word):
 vowwel='aeiou'
 c=''
 x=False
 for l in word :

  if any(y==l for y in vowwel):
   x=True

  if x==True:
    c+=l 
 if x==False:
  c= 'No vowel' 

 return c
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on _Code Review_.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use extra boolean since you have `any`. This will make it faster and more redeable:

```
def start_with_vowel(word):
     vowwel='aeiou'
     c=''
     for l in word :
        if any(y==l for y in vowwel):
            c+=l 
        else:
            c= 'No vowel' 
     return c
```

Comment: `any(y==l for y in vowwel)` will loop through all vowels and perform a comparison with `l`. Wouldn't it be more efficient to loop through `vowwel` and stop checking once a match is found? Nitpicking, of course. No practical difference in speed.

Comment: the expected result is below :
 >>> startWithVowel('apple')
    'apple'
    >>> startWithVowel('google')
    'oogle'
    >>> startWithVowel('xyz')
    'No vowel' and if i run your version something is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def start_with_vowel(word):
vowel = 'aeiou'
for s in word.lower() :
    if any(y==s for y in vowel):
        return word[word.lower().index(s):]
return 'No Vowel' 

assert start_with_vowel('') =='No Vowel'
assert start_with_vowel('Iota') =='Iota'
assert start_with_vowel('lOllipop') =='Ollipop'
assert start_with_vowel('Bagheera') =='agheera'
assert start_with_vowel('crwth') =='No Vowel'
```